# Vagrant guest's /var/www freezes when doing config.vm.synced

Tags: ubuntu, windows, vagrant

I reviewed all synced_folder configuration @ Vagrant's website...

Host OS: Windows 7
Guest OS: Ubuntu

this is my Vagrantfile config:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|  
    config.vm.box = "base"
    config.vm.hostname = "daison.vagrant.me"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    #config.vm.synced_folder "C:\\Users\\daison\\vagrant\\src\\www", "/var/www"
end
```

I also do `C:\Users\daison\vagrant\> vagrant reload`

I can access my the Ubuntu's apache, by running `127.0.0.1:8080 or 192.168.33.10 or daison.vagrant.me:8080` -- **IN MY HOST**

so by removing the `commented synced_folder` and reloading again the vagrant. The results of all the IP ADDRESSES AND MY VIRTUALHOST ARE **NOT ACCESSIBLE** -- **INT MY HOST**

I tried accessing `vagrant ssh`

```
vagrant@daison: cd /var/www
vagrant@daison: /var/www$ ls
```

and nothing showing up...

I also tried to create a `folder` just to see if the synced_folder really works even if it freezes the guest folder

```
vagrant@daison: /var/www$ mkdir thisFolderWillAlsoShareToHost
```

Then a folder in my `C:\Users\daison\vagrant\src\www` created **IN MY HOST**.

---

I also tried to change the synced_folders to `"/vagrant/sample"` just to test if `/vagrant/sample` will be freeze the same with `/var/www`, after reloading the vagrant.

The result is; I can access the web-server, ofcourse it is not part in `/var/www`, but using `ls` inside `/vagrant/sample` freezes also.

Maybe someone could help? Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "freeze"? In the host, what is the output of `dir C:\Users\daison\vagrant\src\www`?

Comment: @ the guest station, I went to /var/www/ and tried to use `ls` and nothing shows up BUT! I can create folders like `mkdir waaaa` and ,@ the host station the `waaaa` folder also shows up, I can't even refresh my host browser using `daison.vagrant.me:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080` or `192.168.33.10`; If i'll be commenting my custom synced_folder, the LAMP server works perfectly, I can even browse it thru the HOST using the ip-addresses and my virtual-host

Answer (score 0):

From the way you're describing your problem, it sounds like you created some websites on your guest, set up a synced folder, and expected vagrant to perform a bidirectional sync between the host and the guest. That's not how it works. What enabling a synced folder does is mount a folder from your host in your guest. The contents from the host mask any existing contents on the guest. Here's what I mean:

Without a synced folder

```
> dir C:\Users\daison\vagrant\src\www
a_file_on_the host

$ ls /var/www
a_file_on_the_guest
```

With those folders synced.

```
> dir C:\Users\daison\vagrant\src\www
a_file_on_the host

$ ls /var/www
a_file_on_the host
```

If you created a new file from within the guest while the folders were synced

```
> dir C:\Users\daison\vagrant\src\www
a_file_on_the host
file_created_while_synced

$ ls /var/www
a_file_on_the host
file_created_while_synced
```

Disable the synced folder, and now you'd see

```
> dir C:\Users\daison\vagrant\src\www
a_file_on_the host
file_created_while_synced

$ ls /var/www
a_file_on_the_guest
```

So if your websites were created in the guest, they're not available any more while you sync */var/www*. That's why the web server "freezes".